# create a pubsub node in xmpp

Tags: xmpp, publish-subscribe, ejabberd

I am trying create a node in ejabber using XMPP and BOSH Manager. But I want to know what values need to be passed in a create node stanza.

Following is the format of create node stanza but i am not be able to create it so can anyone tell me what values need to be passed 
in `<formvalue> <tovalue> <nodevalue>`

```
<iq type='set'
    from='<fromvalue>'
    to='<tovalue>'
    id='create1'>
  <pubsub xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub'>
    <create node='<nodevalue>'/>
  </pubsub>
</iq>
```

Note:
I am using ejabbered and BOSH url is `http://example.com:5280/xmpp-http-bind`.

i tried this and i am getting  **feature-not-implemented error**

```
<body rid='95507820' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='5c4fbfe432babab58fe5e39367fc1704c06ddfd7'>
   <presence xmlns='jabber:client'>
      <priority>-1</priority>
   </presence>
<iq to='example.com' type='set' xmlns='jabber:client' id='3742:sendIQ'>
   <pubsub xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub'>
     <create/>
     <configure/>
  </pubsub>
</iq>
</body>
```

i tried another way too and in that case i am getting **creation failed with jid-malformed**

```
<body rid='2037203608' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='2a198251db476ef0490a4d3f591468b69edaf35b'>
   <presence xmlns='jabber:client'>
     <priority>-1</priority>
   </presence>
<iq to='example.com' type='set' xmlns='jabber:client' id='7398:sendIQ'>
  <pubsub xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub'>
    <create node='draw'/>
  </pubsub>
 </iq>
```

i tried with **filepath** too but i am getting **creation failed with forbidden**

```
<body rid='358865391' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='0f7cf72754f0fc3b0b04c8c0bb488e816380d741'>
    <presence xmlns='jabber:client'>
        <priority>-1</priority>
    </presence>
    <iq to='pubsub.example.com' type='set' xmlns='jabber:client' id='8556:sendIQ'>
        <pubsub xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub'>
            <create node='/home/localhost/john/draw/'/>
        </pubsub>
    </iq>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for a start here's the relevant [documentation](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0060.html#owner-create).

- `from` is the jid of the user sending the iq, as is always the case when sending an iq.
- `to` is the Publish-Subscribe service you want to create the node to. A typical value would be `pubsub.example.com` but that really depends on your server's configuration.
- `node` takes the id of the node you create. In some server configurations this has a semantic meaning (typically a path) but try out with `mynode` for instance.

It is possible that the user sending the iq is not allowed to create the node, or that the service does not support it. One could only tell depending on the error stanza if any, so if the above does not work, do post the error you get.

Comment: Example.com cannot be the service. Put whatever you put as the pubsub service in your ejabberd.cfg

Comment: well where can i find it in ejabberd.cfg as here for privacy reason i have mentioned `example.com` in a real its `nxxxxxxt.com` , is there any special place to specify service for pubsub in .cfg file ?

Comment: The service name is most likely already "pubsub" by default.  So have you tried pubsub.example.com.  Also, ejabberd used to require a hierarchical node name (like a file path), but I don't know if that is still the case or not.

Comment: so i have to write some file path like `/home/localhost/john/draw` to service name ?

Comment: you get forbidden. The user trying to create the node has no right to do so, you need to configure the permissions in your ejabberd.cfg. @robin ejabberd takes paths or simple keys depending on the plugin.

Comment: @ggozad you are right i made it working by changing `{access, pubsub_createnode, [{allow, all}]}` but i got some other issues for that i will create another post